# discord.py slash commands - "This interaction failed" on long running functions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a long running function which takes about 20 or so seconds to complete. When the function is complete, it sends the results as a message to Discord.

If I run this function by typing in a usual command (no slash commands) it works completely fine and I see the results sent to Discord.

But if I invoke the function through a slash command, Discord tells me "This interaction failed" and then shortly after I see the results in the message. So the function is working completely fine, but the slash commands seems to be under the belief that they are failing.

To test this, I got a basic function:

```
@slash.slash(name="test",
             guild_ids=[123,456],
             description="This is just a test command, nothing more.",
             options=[
                 create_option(
                     name="optone",
                     description="This is the first option we have.",
                     option_type=3,
                     required=False
                 )
             ])
async def test(ctx, optone: str):
    await ctx.send(content=f"I got you, you said {optone}!")
```

If I invoke this through slash command, no problem. I then put a breakpoint on `await ctx.send...` and run the command again. Discord says "This interaction failed". I continue debug execution and then the message is sent.

Why do slash commands think the command is failing, when it isn't, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have included what slash commands package your are using, but (from the command syntax) I am assuming you are using [discord-py-slash-command](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io).

From the the [package](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) and [discord's developer](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#responding-to-an-interaction) documentation:

> In this example we responded directly to the interaction, however if you want to delay the response (if you need more than 3 seconds before sending a message) you can defer the response for up to 15 minutes with ctx.defer(), this displays a “Bot is thinking” message. However do not defer the response if you will be able to respond (send) within three seconds as this will cause a message to flash up

Add ctx.defer() to the top of your command.
If you need more time than 15 seconds, you can send a message and edit it later.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work at first but it does now. I think something may have been cached on bot or client side. Thanks for your help!